# Scala type parameter bounds

Tags: scala, type-systems, type-parameter

I'm having some trouble understanding scala's type bounds system. What I'm trying to do is make a holder class that holds items of type T that can iterate over items of type A. What I have so far is:

```
class HasIterable[T <: Iterable[A], A](item:T){
  def printAll = for(i<-item) println(i.toString)
}

val hello = new HasIterable("hello")
```

The class itself successfully compiles but attempting to create the `hello` value gives me this error:

```
<console>:11: error: inferred type arguments [java.lang.String,Nothing] do 
not conform to class HasIterable's type parameter bounds [T <: Iterable[A],A]
   val hello = new HasIterable("hello")
               ^
```

I would have expected `hello` to resolve as a `HasIterable[String, Char]` in that case. How is this problem solved?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`String` itself is not a subtype of `Iterable[Char]`, but its [pimp](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766), `WrappedString`, is. In order to allow your definition to make use of implicit conversions, you need to use a [view bound](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/130) (`<%`) instead of an [upper type bound](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/136) (`<:`):

```
class HasIterable[T <% Iterable[A], A](item:T){
    def printAll = for(i<-item) println(i.toString)
}
```

Now your example will work:

```
scala> val hello = new HasIterable("hello")              
hello: HasIterable[java.lang.String,Char] = HasIterable@77f2fbff
```

Comment: would you mind explaining why this works (and the other doesn't)?

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! And yes, why does <% work in this case? --aha I see your edit. Thanks :)