# What does this sign "<:" mean in scala?

Tags: scala

I am going through some scala code. I have come across a sign "<:". What does it mean?

Here is the following code.

```
abstract class HierarchicalDatabaseObject[TParent <: DatabaseObject](databaseId: String) extends DatabaseObject(databaseId)
```

Comment: It's upper type bound: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/136

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala type parameter bounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713385/scala-type-parameter-bounds)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do all of Scala's symbolic operators mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888944/what-do-all-of-scalas-symbolic-operators-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a upper bounded wildcard. If you're familiar with Java it's like `? extends DatabaseObject`.

It means, that the Type you put in has to be a Subtype of `DatabaseObject`.
This basically guarantees, that your generic Type has atleast all the same methods and properties that `DatabaseObject` has, making it much more useful, than when unbound.

You can check out more examples in the [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/upper-type-bounds.html).